# Can you prove that the sum of the x coordinate and y coordinate products equal cos(θ) without using the law of cosines?

Tags: geometry, vectors, circles

When the product of the x coordinate of a point on a unit circle and the x coordinate of another point on that circle is summed with the product of their respective y values, the result will be cos(θ) where θ is the angle between the two radii.

$$x_{u1}\times x_{u2}+y_{u1}\times y_{u2}=cos(\theta)$$

I've pondered this for a while, read through online resources on vector projections and drawn some diagrams to try and understand this relationship better. However, I'm still slightly confused about how to prove it besides deriving from the law of cosines. Is there another more elementary proof?

[image: Unit Circle]

Here's the derivation from the law of cosines:

[image: cosine rule derivation]

Is there a more elementary proof that as vectors are rotated through the circle at a fixed angle, the decrease in the value of the product of the y coordinates is proportional to the increase in the product of the x coordinates?

I wonder if there's some way to link the relationship to the formula of a circle rather than deriving from the law of cosines?

For two vectors which overlap each other (θ=0) the x, y coordinate "product proportion" is given by the formula used to plot the circle.

[image: unit vector calculations]

As shown above this proportionality is true for cases where $θ>0$ or where one of the coordinates $= 0$, which is tantalisingly close to proof, but I don't think that's enough to prove a general case.

Essentially, I want to prove that as α changes, the changes in $x_1x_2$ and $y_1y_2$ are proportional such that:

$$x_{1b}x_{2b}+y_{1b}y_{2b}=y_{1a}y_{2a}+x_{1a}x_{2a}$$

Comment: You are missing the point that $x_{u1}=\cos \theta_1$ etc.

Comment: Which "cosine rule" did you use in your proof?

Comment: The law of cosines. I've updated the answer to show the proof.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit jimjim? I understand that the y coordinate of a unit vector is equal to cos(θ) where θ is the angle between that vector and the y axis (and in this case the length of the circumference) but I still can't see the connection between that and the "proportionality of the products".

Comment: first, well done on more explanation. what you need is either rotation on unit circle by using matrices, or complex numbers. either method makes cosine or sine rule a trivial case of more general formulas. I think that might be actually how one derives the cosine rule.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameteric equation for a unit circle is $(x,y) \equiv (\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$. Thus, $$x_1x_2 + y_1y_2 = \cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2 + \sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2 \\
= \cos(\theta_1 - \theta_2) \\
= \cos\theta$$
Where $\theta$ is the angle between the two radii, as shown in your figure.

Comment: How did you get from 
$\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2 + \sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2$  to $ \cos(\theta_1 - \theta_2) $ without using the cosine rule that this question is about?

Comment: @jimjim It is not clear to me (from the current form of the question) what "cosine rule" the question is about. Since it's hard for me to imagine why one would need a "more straightforward" proof than this answer, I would guess that OP originally used a different "cosine rule" than the one used here. It is possible, of course, that OP really wanted to ask for a more *elementary* proof rather than a more *straightforward* one.

Comment: I've clarified which cosine rule I used and updated the terminology.

Comment: Could you please explain how you equated $cos\theta_1 cos\theta_2 + sin\theta_1 sin\theta_2$ to $cos(\theta_1 - \theta_2)$

Comment: @JoshHardman : That is the cosine rule written in a different form.

Comment: @JoshHardman that's the [difference formula for cosine](https://brownmath.com/twt/sumdiff.htm), not the cosine rule (cosine rule applies in triangles)

Comment: Thank you! Found a wonderful diagram linked in the textbook which provides a proof of this relationship for smaller angles. A little disappointed I couldn't find an even more elementary way to prove this visually, but at least I can easily show the maths is solid even if it probably appears somewhat obscure to the uninitiated.

Comment: Here are the figures http://math.uaa.alaska.edu/~smiley/trigproofs.html

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this to supplement Aniruddha's answer and document the process I went through to arrive at a satisfactory solution.

https://myblog1603.wordpress.com/2020/10/08/going-round-in-circles-geometric-proof-of-a-deceptive-formula/

The image is a sketch of a figure which provides the elementary proof and format I was looking to obtain.

[image: geometric proof of trigonometric subtraction formula superimposed on a section of a unit circle]